# Rails app reviews are not saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a book review application from on online tutorial. I am trying to save a book review with a form. I have a book table and a reviews table. If the book review saves, I've told the review form to redirect to the book show page. If not, render 'new' again. I get zero errors when I try to save. It just puts me back on the new review page. I went into the console, and the reviews are not being saved. I don't know what's going on. Can someone help?

Here is my books controller:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :edit, :index, :show] 


def index
    @books = Book.all
end

def new
    @book = current_user.books.new
end

def create 
    @book = current_user.books.build(book_params)
    if @book.save 
        redirect_to books_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
end 

def edit 
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
end

def update
@book = Book.find(params[:id])
if @book.update(book_params)
    redirect_to book_path(@book)
else
    render "edit"
end
end 


def destroy
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    @book.destroy
    if @book.destroy 
        redirect_to books_path
    else
        render 'show_books_path'
    end
end

private
    def book_params
        params.require(:book).permit(:title, :description, :author, :category_id, :book_img)
    end
end
```

Here is my reviews controller:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_book


def new 
    @review = Review.new
end


def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.book_id = @book.id
    @review.user_id = current_user.id
    if @review.save
        redirect_to book_path(@book)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end



def edit

end

def update

end

def destroy

end

private

    def review_params 
        params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :comment)
    end

    def find_book
        @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
    end
end
```

Here is my review model:

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :books
belongs_to :users

end
```

Here is my book model:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :user
has_many :reviews

has_attached_file :book_img, styles: { book_index: "250x350>", book_show:    "400x600>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :book_img, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

I'm using a devise form. Here is what I have:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@book, @book.reviews.build]) do |f| %>
 <p>Rating</p>
 <%= f.input :rating, label: false, :class => "input" %>
 <p>Comment</p>
 <%= f.text_area :comment, label: false, :class => "input" %>
 <%= f.button :submit, :class => "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


devise_for :users

resources :books do 
    resources :reviews
end

root "books#index"

end
```

I'm really not sure what's going on here. When I go into the console, the reviews are not being saved. Eventually, I want to display them, but I haven't gotten to that step. Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Can you show html code generated in your form on the page?

Comment: The reason that you're not getting any errors is because you aren't asking for them. Try using `puts @book.errors.to_s` before `render 'new'` in the `create` method in the controller to print the errors to the console. However, I do notice that in `review_params` you require `:rating` and `:comment`, but your `Review` model doesn't seem to contain these fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that in your `Review` model you have this:

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :books
  belongs_to :users

end
```

When it should be like this:

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user

end
```

`belongs_to` associations have to use the singular term